# PhpStorm icon near file name in Project View

Tags: icons, phpstorm

What mean this icon(`checked`) near gulpfile.js ?
Please look image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bookmark -- you have bookmarked a file with ordinary bookmark.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/navigating-with-bookmarks.html

---

You can remove it in the same way how you set it up. Few ways actually:

1. Select that file in Project View panel and while focus is still there activate `Navigate | Bookmarks | Toggle Bookmark` (<kbd>F11</kbd> using Default keymap on Linux/Windows)
2. Bring *Bookmarks screen* in and remove any unwanted bookmark from there: `Navigate | Bookmarks | Show Bookmarks` (<kbd>Shift + F11</kbd> using Default keymap on Linux/Windows)